# Is the CSV mode special in the sqlite3 shell?

Tags: sqlite

If I were to format something in comma separated form, which one of the following is better practice:

1. `.separated ","`
2. `.mode csv`

Are there any major difference between the above two?

Answer (score 1):

`.separator ","` just changes the column separator.

When in CSV mode, the `sqlite3` command-line shell surrounds field values with quotes when needed:

```
> .mode list          (default)
> .separator ","
> SELECT 1, 2, ',';
1,2,,
> .mode csv
> SELECT 1, 2, ',';
1,2,","
```